# RepositoryItemReader nativeQuery

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using Spring Boot + Spring Batch + Spring JPA Data, and i am trying to use `RepositoryItemReader` from Spring Batch.

The batch is working fine for the giving methods (without nativeQuery), but i am facing this issue giving native queries a try.

The issue it is always returns an empty array (row count is always 0).

Below are the console logs:

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM QUOTE_OFFER_FULFILLMENT QOF WHERE QOF.STATUS=? OR QOF.STATUS=?  
#pageable
 order by QOF.id desc limit ?
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - bindNamedParameters() FULFILLMENT_READY -> 1 [1]
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - bindNamedParameters() FAILED -> 2 [2]
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.stat.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM QUOTE_OFFER_FULFILLMENT QOF WHERE QOF.STATUS=? OR QOF.STATUS=?  
#pageable
 order by QOF.id desc, time: 1ms, rows: 0
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
```

My repository method:

```
@Component
@Repository
public interface QuoteOfferFulfillmentRepository
        extends JpaRepository<QuoteOfferFulfillment, Long> {
@query(value = "SELECT * FROM QUOTE_OFFER_FULFILLMENT QOF WHERE QOF.STATUS=?1 OR QOF.STATUS=?2 \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
Page findTempByStatus(QuoteOfferFulfillmentStatus status,
QuoteOfferFulfillmentStatus status1, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And my BatchConfiguration:

```
@Bean 
public RepositoryItemReader reader() {
    RepositoryItemReader fullfillment = new RepositoryItemReader();
    fullfillment.setRepository(fulfillmentRepository);
    fullfillment.setMethodName("findTempByStatus");
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(QuoteOfferFulfillmentStatus.FULFILLMENT_READY);
    list.add(QuoteOfferFulfillmentStatus.FAILED);
    fullfillment.setPageSize(40);
    fullfillment.setArguments(list);
    HashMap<String, Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
    sorts.put("id", Direction.DESC);
    fullfillment.setSort(sorts);
    return fullfillment;
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `countQuery` parameter to you native `@Query` to define the size of your pages.

From the [Spring Data JPA docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query):

> Spring Data JPA does not currently support dynamic sorting for native
>   queries, because it would have to manipulate the actual query
>   declared, which it cannot do reliably for native SQL. You can,
>   however, use native queries for pagination by specifying the count
>   query yourself, as shown in the following example:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**EDIT**

[Minimal working example on Github](https://github.com/gpassini/Spring-Batch-RepositoryItemReader-NativeQuery-Example)

Comment: Hi @gustavo Passini, Thanks for responding. based on your suggestion below are the changes, @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM QUOTE_OFFER_FULFILLMENT QOF WHERE QOF.STATUS=?1 OR QOF.STATUS=?2  \n#pageable\n", countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM offers.QUOTE_OFFER_FULFILLMENT QOF WHERE QOF.STATUS=?1 OR QOF.STATUS=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<QuoteOfferFulfillment> findTempByStatus(QuoteOfferFulfillmentStatus status,
            QuoteOfferFulfillmentStatus status1, Pageable pageable);   But no luck. its a same result. getting results as 0. did i done any thing wrong ??

Comment: Hello @Balakrishna Tirumalasetti. You are welcome. I'm sorry, but I can't see where the problem might be now. I have uploaded to my Github a minimal working example. I hope it can help you out.